# Multiple answers on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm working on asynchronous file upload. I want to call File dialog after clicking on button, then read file information (name, size) then eventually send them to server. My problem is: after first click script sends one pack of data (that is great) BUT after second click it sends two packs of data, third click = three packs etc.

What is a problem and how to repair that?

JS:

```
function FileAdd(){
$('#input_file').trigger("click");

$('#input_file').on('change', function(){
    input = $('#input_file')[0];
    console.log(input.files[0]);
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="File_add" type="button" onclick="FileAdd();">+ Add</button>
<input type="file" multiple="" name="files" id="input_file">
```

**EDIT:**
Solution was simple:
put part of code inside $(document).ready(function(){}

Comment: It's strange, because, when you click on the button you launch a function who click on the button too + each time you click you add a trigger.. I don't really understand what your looking for but you may extract `$.on` from `FileAdd()`

Comment: If you found a solution to your question on your own, please provide it in a separate answer instead of an edit to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are registering a new `change` event every time the button is clicked.

Could you move your event registration outside of the function?

```
$('#input_file').on('change', function(){
    input = $('#input_file')[0];
    console.log(input.files[0]);
});
```

---

```
function FileAdd(){
  $('#input_file').trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Trigger change or click???

Comment: I did that. There is File dialogue, but no console logs.

Comment: Quite likely because you're not registering the event within `DOM ready`. Enclose it with `$(function() { <event reg> });`